# Asp.net fileUploader(brettle.web) is not working on post back

Tags: asp.net

I am using a third party file uploader which is same as asp.net file uploader control.
On a page before post back(clicking a button in gridview) the file name gets empty from file uploader and on code behind can't get file.
There were update panels on page. I have also removed them but no affect.

Comment: Have you set autopostback property of the control to false?

Comment: No, it gets post back.

Comment: I meant, try setting the property at design time, as AutoPostBack = "false"

Comment: do you add the file uploader dynamically?

Comment: which third party uploader you are using?

Comment: instead of accessing the file inside the uploader, have you tried cycling through `foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in Request.Files)` ? whatever uploader you use doesnt matter in this case as all files are being posted in the request. cycle through them on `page_load` and check if `Request.Files` is empty. you might want to wrap it in `if(IsPostBack)` to make sure it executes on post back only

Comment: @Banana no file in request.files.
Actually File uploader is inside a grid, it gets post back by pressing a button inside grid view.
Before post back the file disappears from file uploader.

Comment: Are you sure the file disappears from the uploader before postback? If yes, then you might be hiding/removing the uploader or its container using javascrip before posting back . If you do, note that setting display none or removing the uploader will remove it from the posted request as well

Comment: Try commenting out all your JavaScript and simply submitting using a submit type input and see if u still dont get files

Comment: @Banana: After commenting all javascript, problem is still there.

Comment: then most likely your page is being refreshed before it reaches the code block where you check for files. put a break point in the very beginning of `Page_Load` (or `Page_Init` if you have it) and go line by line. also, if you are using a master page break in it's Page Load and check if it redirects you accidentally (or intentionally and you forgot)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the Brettle.Web FAQ http://neatupload.codeplex.com/documentation and found the following answer to a very similar problem:

Q: Why are filenames cleared on postback?
A: Browser security restrictions prevent the server from set the names of files to upload.

Comment: But on another page the same control is working fine in same scenario.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JavaScript console that could prevent the proper operation of this control? 
Yet another way to isolate the issue is to start removing one by one the parts of the page/code until you find exactly which one is causing the issue.